# Passing PHP variable to vue.js vue component

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js

I am working on a wordpress site where I need to pass a php string variable to a .vue component so that one of the vue variable will reflect the value of the php varaible

index.php

```
<?php 
$foo = 72;
?>

<div id='app'></div>
```

app.js

```
import App from './views/App';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
});
```

./views/App.vue

```
<template>
<h1>{{ foo }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'App',
 data() {
  return {
   foo: ''
  }
 }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

As you can see in index.php, $foo = 72.  I want that 72 value will be pass on to $foo in App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of WordPress, you would call [`wp_localize_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) with the required data so that it becomes available in the global space of the script that initializes your Vue.js application.

Assuming you have registered `vue-script` beforehand:

```
<?php
$foo = 42;
wp_localize_script('vue-script', 'foo', $foo);
wp_enqueue_script('vue-script');
```

Then in the script you could use [propsData](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData) to pass down `foo` when creating the Vue instance:

```
import App from './views/App';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  propsData: { foo }
});
```

...then replacing data with props in App.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: ['foo'],
}
</script>
```

I haven't tested this myself, so YMMV but this is basically how you should approach this. Providing a little more context could point to other solutions, like ready-made Vue.js / WordPress frameworks such as [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/) or [NuePress](https://nuepress.kmr.io/)

Comment: I added wp_localize_script in my functions.php and it works

Now I have hard time passing the new created JS object to my Vue component.  

I tried following your tutorial but it keeps saying undefined.

Comment: If you can log your value using `console.log(window.foo)` from the `created` lifecycle hook of your App, maybe you can assign the value there or directly inside the `data` function?

Comment: This did it for me. I was able to see my data when I `console.log(window.foo)`, which helped solve all the other unknowns